# Is it possible to play music in the cockpit?

Tags: cockpit

I was wondering that if a pilot's flight had been delayed or a pilot had nothing to do, would it be possible for a pilot to play music in the cockpit?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16334/62)

Comment: Are you talking about commercial pilots or GA? My audio panel has a music input, and even a phone input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it allowed to listen to music while piloting a plane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16334/is-it-allowed-to-listen-to-music-while-piloting-a-plane)

Comment: This question asks, and the answers address, is it ***possible***, while the suggested dupe discusses, is it ***allowed***. Not really the same question, nor quite the same answers. Voting to leave open.

Comment: Question does not exclude the hypothetic wish to bring a saxophone or a triangle, the latter having more chances to jam flight controls if lost in cockpit.

Comment: @qqjkztd, Well, even [a more advanced music making](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ykQFrL0X74) has been done this way :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the proper equipment, it is possible.

For example on the Garmin GTN 750. Music is listed as a service on this avionic.

[image: GTN 750 Service Page]

[image: GTN 750 Music Page]

And you can even create multiple music channels and assign it to different people on the intercom, of course with mute feature when someone speaks either on the intercom or radio.

[image: GTN Audio Panel]

Answer (score 17):

Depending on the equipment in the aircraft, the answer may very well be yes. A lot of modern headsets in civilian aircraft (particularly those with active noise reduction) have [bluetooth capability that allows music streaming](http://www.lightspeedaviation.com/b75b2fb84ea485ae93ab76c2e06c19e7/content/lightspeedaviation/file/ZuluUG_B3_2015.pdf). Some more modern [audio panels even have music inputs now](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/93#specs). I even flew in an Archer that had a CD player on the panel and wired into the audio panel.

If you are lucky enough to have an automatic direction finder (ADF) eating up useful load in your aircraft [you may be able to tune into AM radio stations.](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/commercial-am-stations-on-the-adf.44882/) This may have contributed to the crash of [Varig Flight 254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varig_Flight_254).

While you are [legally allowed to do this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16334/is-it-allowed-to-listen-to-music-while-piloting-a-plane) (at least in small planes) the sterile cockpit rules that most if not all air carriers have prevent professional pilots from doing so, as @Carlo Felicione points out in the comments

Comment: Good post, though I might add some information in there about sterile cockpit rules for professional pilots .

Comment: The politics of pilot distractions has changed in the last 15 years so things may have changed. But 15years ago Atlas freighter pilots were allowed (and somewhat encouraged) to use laptops for movies and iPods for music while in the cockpit to help stave off boredom on long flights. The reasoning was that kept their brain alert and awake and increased safety.