# What do pilots do, when there is a long wait before take-off, after gates are closed?

Tags: pilots

Pilots are supposed to carry out the mandatory checks before the flight take-off or taxi. But what happens when there is a delay, when the aircraft cannot push back from the gate, due to non-clearance from ATC, or due to heavy traffic etc.

- Do the pilots, re-run the checks, or carry out more extensive checks of the aircraft?
- Do the pilots just chit-chat, eat, or make phone calls to their family?
- Is there any standard procedure to be followed during this wait time?

[image]

Edit: As someone tagged this as duplicate, my question no where suggests time spent by pilots during long haul flight, its about what they do when the pushback is delayed. Hope it helps.

Comment: They are constantly on the phone with company, handling, airport, ATC, etc. to try to get going. It is extremely frustrating for pilots to get delayed, so they do everything they can to avoid it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (in a general sense) [How do long-haul pilots cope with boredom?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13422/how-do-long-haul-pilots-cope-with-boredom)

Comment: @Dave it's related but I think the types of things the pilots have to do on the ground would be different from during cruise.

Comment: @fooot Agreed I have removed the vote but ill leave the comment as i think it directs to some relevant material.

Comment: @fooot exactly, I provided an edit in my question. Also I don't understand, when only 1 person suggest this is duplicate, how come the question suddenly carries the warning, isn't it supposed to happen after 5 votes?

Comment: Most seem to have tablet flight bags these days, so they could watch an airline disaster movie.

Comment: A ***possible** duplicate* comment appears at any time a duplicate is suggested. It will not be closed as a duplicate until five closevotes happen.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what Daniel listed already, they're also nervously watching the clock.
If they're late by too much they may miss their mandatory crew rest period and have to cancel the flight or hand over to another crew.

This can of course get very expensive for the airline, especially if all or most passengers have to be accommodated in hotels overnight for a departure the next day in case no replacement crew can be arranged or the forced delay causes the flight to be unable to take off due to closing of the departure airport before departure or closing of the destination airport before arrival there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been on many flights with delays, and here's what I've seen/heard. They check often with ground/tower for estimated wheels up time, and any restrictions on slots available at their destination airport. They also check fuel so that if it drops below reserves, they can call to return to the gate for more fuel. Other than  that, just idle chatter I guess.